# why input events are not being captured at sometimes, in c++

Tags: c++, winapi, input, mouseevent

```cpp
#include <Windows.h>
#include <vector>
using std::vector;

class event_handler{
private:
    DWORD n_evnts_read=0,n_evnts=0,evnt_type=0,mode=0;

public:
    int rec_indx = 0;
    vector<INPUT_RECORD> inrec;
    KEY_EVENT_RECORD kev;
    MOUSE_EVENT_RECORD mev;
    HANDLE hndlin = GetStdHandle(STD_INPUT_HANDLE);
    HANDLE hndlout = GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE);

    int cap_evnt_key(){

        n_evnts_read = n_evnts = evnt_type = 0;

        GetNumberOfConsoleInputEvents(hndlin, &n_evnts_read);
        if (n_evnts_read){
            inrec.resize(n_evnts_read);
            ReadConsoleInput(hndlin, &inrec[0], inrec.size(), &n_evnts);
            for(DWORD m = 0; m < n_evnts; m++)
                if (inrec[m].EventType == KEY_EVENT)
                {
                    kev = inrec[m].Event.KeyEvent;
                    fflush(stdin);
                    return 5;
                }
        }
        return -1;
    }

    int cap_evnt_mouse(){

        n_evnts_read = n_evnts = evnt_type = mode = 0;

        GetNumberOfConsoleInputEvents(hndlin, &n_evnts_read);
        if (n_evnts_read){
            inrec.resize(n_evnts_read);
            ReadConsoleInput(hndlin, &inrec[0], inrec.size(), &n_evnts);
            for(DWORD m = 0; m < n_evnts; m++)
                if (inrec[m].EventType == MOUSE_EVENT)
                {
                    mev = inrec[m].Event.MouseEvent;
                    fflush(stdin);
                    return 5;
                }
        }
        return -1;
    }

    DWORD key(){
        if (!kev.bKeyDown)
            return kev.wVirtualKeyCode;
        else
            return 0;
    }

    bool left_click(){
        if (mev.dwButtonState == FROM_LEFT_1ST_BUTTON_PRESSED)
            return 1;
        else
            return 0;
    }
} evnt_hndlr;   

void test()
{
    short n = 0;
    COORD pos;

    while (1)
    {
        if (evnt_hndlr.cap_evnt_key() == 5)
        {
            if (evnt_hndlr.key() == VK_RIGHT)
                //do something
            else if (evnt_hndlr.key() == VK_LEFT)
                //do something
        }
        else if (evnt_hndlr.cap_evnt_mouse() == 5)
        {
            if (evnt_hndlr.left_click() == 1)
                //do something
        }
    }
    exit(0);
}
```

Now, when I run `test()` inside `main()` and try to capture a mouse/keyboard event, sometimes it gives me the signal that the required event was captured, but sometimes it misses that event.

Kindly give me a reliable way of capturing input events (especially when both mouse and keyboard events need to be read simultaneously), because this procedure is hanging (if I'm not using the wrong word). Also, explain to me why this problem is happening. It's very bad for users indeed.

Comment: What do you think happens when `cap_evnt_key()` is called and there are mouse events in the queue? You throw them away! Same with `cap_evnt_mouse()` with key events. So of course you lose events sometimes. So, you need to rethink your entire approach. I would suggest moving `GetNumberOfConsoleInputEvents()`/`ReadConsoleInput()` into another method that moves pending events into a cache, and then have another method that pops events from that cache, going back to the console to cache new events whenever the cache is empty.

Comment: 1: Isn't it a problem of syncronization of console, or something like that? 2:Here, can't the vector `inrec` act like a cache buffer? I move the events whenever i press some key from keyboard or mouse into `inrec`, and then retrieves the required one after capturing it, and discard it afterwards,  doesn't that sounds like a cache? Or something else have to be made and maintained?

Comment: 1: no, because the problem is your logic is retrieving events and throwing them away. 2: it can, if you were using it more effectively. For instance, whenever you call `cap_evnt_...()` and there are any new input events available, you *wipe out* the current vector content and refill it with only the *latest* events, without checking if it *already* contained earlier events you are interested in. You need to *append* new events to the vector, not *replace* it.

Comment: `int cap_evnt_key(){

        n_evnts_read=n_evnts=evnt_type=0;

        GetNumberOfConsoleInputEvents(hndlin,&n_evnts_read);
        if(n_evnts_read){
            inrec.resize(inrec.size()+n_evnts_read);
            ReadConsoleInput(hndlin,&inrec[inrec.size()-n_evnts_read],n_evnts_read,&n_evnts);
            for(int m=0;m<inrec.size();m++)
                if(inrec[m].EventType==KEY_EVENT)
                {   kev=inrec[m].Event.KeyEvent;
                    return 5;
                }}return -1;}` have a look at my modified version of cap_evnt_key(), according to your advise.

Comment: I don't delete the contents of `inrec` and keep appending the next read events, until the desired work is done. Once it is done, I `resize()` it to 0, is it a good way of maintaining cache? If not, kindly explain to me. Because problem has gone more worse (obviously, by my poor logic :) )

Comment: your new code is ignoring existing events in the vector unless there are new events available to read. Also, you are not removing events from the vector as you process them. And since you store both kinds of events in a single vector, resizing the vector to 0 will lose ALL events. Say you finish processing key events, you will lose mouse events. And vice versa. I still think your entire approach is wrong and needs to be redesigned from scratch.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/235772/discussion-between-ammar-mujtaba-tariq-and-remy-lebeau).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not processing every event that is read.  Your code has the potential to throw away a lot of events. Each time you call `cap_evnt_...()`, if there are any new events available to read, you throw away any events you have already read into the `vector` that have not been processed yet.

Try something more like this instead:

```cpp
#include <Windows.h>
#include <vector>

class event_handler{
private:
    std::vector<INPUT_RECORD> evnts;
    INPUT_RECORD inrec;
    HANDLE hndlin = GetStdHandle(STD_INPUT_HANDLE);
    HANDLE hndlout = GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE);

public:
    int cap_evnt_read() {
        if (evnts.empty()) {
            DWORD n_evnts = 0;
            GetNumberOfConsoleInputEvents(hndlin, &n_evnts);
            if (n_evnts == 0) return -1;
            evnts.resize(n_evnts);
            ReadConsoleInput(hndlin, &evnts[0], n_evnts, &n_evnts);
        }
        inrec = evnts.front();
        evnts.erase(events.begin());
        return inrec.EventType;
    }

    DWORD key() const {
        if (!inrec.Event.KeyEvent.bKeyDown)
            return inrec.Event.KeyEvent.wVirtualKeyCode;
        else
            return 0;
    }

    bool left_click() const {
        return (inrec.Event.MouseEvent.dwButtonState == FROM_LEFT_1ST_BUTTON_PRESSED);
    }
}
evnt_hndlr;   

void test()
{
    while (true)
    {
        switch (evnt_hndlr.cap_evnt_read())
        {
            case KEY_EVENT:
            {
                if (evnt_hndlr.key() == VK_RIGHT)
                    // do something
                else if (evnt_hndlr.key() == VK_LEFT)
                    // do something
                break;
            }

            case MOUSE_EVENT:
            {
                if (evnt_hndlr.left_click())
                    // do something
                break;
            }
       }
    }
    exit(0);
}
```

Comment: O that really works! Thanks a lot, i really learned from it.

Comment: Is there any way to capture shortcut keys? i mean `((evnt_hndlr.key()==VK_RIGHT)&&(evnt_hndlr.inrec.Event.KeyEvent.dwControlKeyState==LEFT_ALT_PRESSED))` (Alt+Right) is not evaluating to true.

Comment: @AmmarMujtabaTariq is there a reason why you are checking for `if (!bKeyDown)` (ie key up) instead of `if (bKeyDown)` (ie key down)? You are handling key release events rather than key press events.

Comment: Actually, this technique was to be implemented for mouse click, because when user mistakenly clicks on a button, he should have the time to drag the mouse outside the button and release there, so that the action can be ignored( this happens only if release event is processed). You might know that strategy. And my previous question, you didn't answered it yet :)

Comment: Another problem occurred, I have disabled quick edit mode and enabled window input mode and mouse input mode at the time of starting the program, but even then I have to re-do them in each iteration where `readconsoleinput()` is placed. Otherwise, it doesn't accept mouse inputs, keyboard inputs are fine.

Comment: @AmmarMujtabaTariq "*I have to re-do [window|mouse input mode] in each iteration where `readconsoleinput()` is placed. Otherwise, it doesn't accept mouse inputs*" - resetting the input modes should not be necessary, per Microsoft's documentation.

Comment: but it doesn't accepts inputs otherwise, is it the compiler error or something like that?

Comment: @AmmarMujtabaTariq The compiler does not influence how the API behaves.  Something else is going on.

Comment: OK, another thing that is causing problem is that even after i have written `cursorinfo.bVisible=FALSE`, my cursor is not hiding most of the time(because sometime it works, but not everytime).